# Azure Devops Unable to create service hook programatically due to permission

Tags: azure, azure-devops, hook, webhooks, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm setting up the service hook for project on Azure DevOps by using Rest API (from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#security)

For the same user in that organization, I have successfully created service hook from the project settings (from https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{repo}/_settings/serviceHooks). So it means that I have the right to create the subscription hook.

For programming, I used PAT for authorization with scope code(read, write) (vs.code_write) for the xxx organization. I have tried with the PAT with full_access but didn't work as well.

Here is the request:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/xxx/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=5.0

Header: Authorization: Basic <Base64PAT>
Body: {
  "publisherId": "tfs",
  "eventType": "git.pullrequest.updated",
  "resourceVersion": "1.0",
  "consumerId": "webHooks",
  "consumerActionId": "httpRequest",
  "publisherInputs": {
    "notificationType": "PushNotification",
    "repository": "<repo_id>"
  },
  "consumerInputs": {
    "url": "https://my/receiver/url/"
  }
}
```

Here is the ERROR response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The user '<user_id>\\<email>' does not have permission to edit a subscription.",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Comment: How did you send the request? can you share the code?

Comment: I use postman to make the request.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Devops Unable to create service hook programatically due to permission

According to the error info:

> "The user '\' does not have permission to edit a
>   subscription."

It seems you do not have permission to edit a subscription. As we know, when an event occurs, **all enabled subscription in the project are evaluated, and the consumer action is performed for all matching subscriptions**.

So, we should have the permission to edit a subscription. You can need "`Edit Subscriptions`" and "`view subscriptions`" to set up a subscription. By default, only **project administrators** have these permissions.

Check the [Q & A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops#q-what-permissions-do-i-need-to-set-up-a-subscription) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There seems to be a bug when the `projectId` is not specified in `publisherInputs`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a subscription via the Web UI (you actually have the permission), and the access token is scoped correctly,
but this still fails try adding the `projectId` to `publisherInputs`.

```json
{
  ...
  "publisherInputs": {
    ...
    "projectId": "<guid>"
  },
  ...
}
```

If you don't know how to get the `projectId` try this api:

[MSDN: Projects - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Service hooks are scoped per project, and it is not possible to create service hook for all projects in an Azure DevOps organization.

Therefore it is required to provide `publisherInputs.projectId` in the body.

```
{
  ...
  "publisherInputs": {
    "projectId": "<guid>"
  }
}
```